# Making a big matrix using sub-matrices in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I like to make a 11 x 11 matrix using 5 x 5 matrices as follow.
Is there any way better than this?

```
int csz = 5;
Mat zz = Mat::zeros(csz, csz, CV_32FC1);
Mat oo = Mat::ones(csz, csz, CV_32FC1);
Mat hh = 0.5 * Mat::ones((csz*2 + 1), 1, CV_32FC1);//column matrix
cv::Mat chkpat1((csz * 2 + 1), (csz * 2 + 1), CV_32FC1);
chkpat1(Range(0, 5),Range(0, 5)) = zz;//first quadrant
chkpat1(Range(0, 5),Range(6, 11)) = oo;//second quadrant
chkpat1(Range(5, 11),Range(0, 5)) = oo;//third quadrant
chkpat1(Range(6, 11),Range(6, 11)) = oo;//fourth quadrant
chkpat1(Range(0, 11),Range(5, 6)) = hh;//middle column  
chkpat1(Range(5, 6),Range(0, 11)) = hh.t();//middle row
```

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter, so in that sense it is better:

```
   cv::Mat chkpat1(11, 11, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(1.0f));
   chkpat1(cv::Rect(0, 0, 5, 5)) = cv::Scalar(0.0f);
   chkpat1(cv::Rect(0, 5, 11, 1)) = cv::Scalar(0.5f);
   chkpat1(cv::Rect(5, 0, 1, 11)) = cv::Scalar(0.5f);
```

This produces (which is what I think you wanted):

```
0    0    0    0    0    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
0    0    0    0    0    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
0    0    0    0    0    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
0    0    0    0    0    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
0    0    0    0    0    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
1    1    1    1    1    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
1    1    1    1    1    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
1    1    1    1    1    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
1    1    1    1    1    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
1    1    1    1    1    0.5    1    1    1    1    1
```